# Analyze the runtime characteristics of a HiveQL query without actual execution

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

How can I determine an approximate runtime of a HiveQL query without (a) executing the query or (b) fetching the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HIVE command `EXPLAIN` gives the execution plan of the query. Just add the keyword `EXPLAIN` before the query and execute it.

Otherwise, instead of returning the result, you could return the count of the records from the query. That might provide some insight into the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @visakh the "explain" gives an execution plan. However it is cryptic and does NOT give execution time.  You will have to do a fair amount of analysis on the (potentially copious) output of explain to derive the information you are looking for.

Running "analyze" on the hive tables *helps* but still does not make the explain user friendly.  The "explain" is a feature that my team at a former major employer requested to HortonWorks to improve.

However I disagree with the "count" approach comment :  the "count" typically takes as much time as running the query itself. After all the data has to be fetched and the various filtering and aggregation operations performed in order to return the count. Unfortunately Hive is not intelligent enough to discard the "sorting/ordering" steps when doing the count - so you end up paying essentially the entire "price" of the query.

Comment: @javadba...of course, the count() approach I suggested essentially runs the entire query as it as. I left it as a way to avoid getting the result set dumped on the screen...

Comment: Well your answer does not point that out at all.  Someone not from hiveql background (especially oracle) might think count() were fast.